# Are there any complex application examples in Grakn & Graql?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Are there any existing complex use case examples leveraging GraQL and Grakn beyond the example on github?
https://github.com/graknlabs/examples/tree/master/python/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three main places to look for examples on Grakn:

1. The docs at [dev.grakn.ai](https://dev.grakn.ai)
2. Grakn's [blog](https://blog.grakn.ai)
3. The [examples repo](https://github.com/graknlabs/examples)

You might also want to check out the [BioGrakn](https://github.com/graknlabs/biograkn) project, which augments multiple biomedical datasources and looks for insights across the knowledge graph created. There are [blog posts](https://blog.grakn.ai/biograkn-accelerating-biomedical-knowledge-discovery-with-a-grakn-knowledge-graph-84706768d7d4) on that too.

Comment: please see the following links for articles on BioGrakn: [article 1](https://blog.grakn.ai/using-a-grakn-knowledge-graph-for-biological-sequence-alignment-analysis-592fa962d5e4), [article 2](https://blog.grakn.ai/drug-repositioning-with-a-grakn-ai-knowledge-graph-for-bioinformatics-4701591f38c1)

Comment: and these as well: [article 3](https://blog.grakn.ai/protein-structure-function-prediction-powered-by-a-grakn-knowledge-graph-fea667483e78), [article 4](https://blog.grakn.ai/biomedical-fact-extraction-and-reasoning-knowledge-graphs-from-scientific-text-c5b94f5f5dc9).

Comment: Much appreciated.